# Deleted Ubuntu partion, can't get boot menu up

Tags: boot, grubrescue, partitioning

I deleted my Ubuntu partition by mistake and now I get this error:

```
Error: no such partition 
grub rescue>
```

How do I get my boot options up again so I can load a live CD? The partition it seems to recognize is (hd0,6) but I have no way to boot!

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake not long ago, I used a windows 7 repair disc to get my PC working again(You didn't mention whether or whether not you had a dual-boot setup, deleting the partition broke both OS for me), then added Ubuntu back on. I realize this may not be the best solution (and may not be valid, as I'm assuming you have windows 7) but it worked.